# Посчитать сумму в таблице

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите, как реализовать такой функционал: когда ввожу в поле,например, 40см, число, например 2, то значению поля `bounch` мы присваиваем `bounch = bounch + 2` и в поле `stems` считается такая формула `stems = bounch * txb`

```html
<div class="data-list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно что за `40см`?

Comment: И еще, когда в поле во второй раз число написать то что будет с `bounch`?

Comment: 40cm это name поля, если мы в поле 40см записали число 2 то bouch=bounch+2, если мы еще в поле 50cm записали 5 , то bounch=bounch+5 итого 7 получиться, и т.д.

Comment: А если в `40` написали 2 а потом в то же поле написали 25 то тогда что будет? 2+ 25?

Comment: нет перезаписать т.е. будет 25

Comment: @Aslero: Если я правильно понял, то вам требуется посчитать сумму все колонок "СМ"? Если так, то я поправил ответ для корректной работы.

Comment: ошибка какая-то вылезла

Comment: @Aslero: Код в пост криво вставил. Поправил.

Comment: а еще маленьки вопрос, а если у меня tr строк будет 5? как для каждой считать?

Comment: @Aslero: Тогда надо будет пройти циклом и выполнить подобный код для каждой строки.

Comment: а зачем цикл? например добавил еще 1 строку, первую вот он считает, а во вторую ввожу не считает

Comment: @Aslero: Поправил код так чтоб работали расчеты во всех строках.

Answer (score 3):

Все расчёты начинаются на строке **`tr`** по событию **`onkeyup`**. От неё идёт погружение к потомкам.

```js
function foo(el) {
  let inputs = el.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    inputsToSum = el.getElementsByClassName('class');
  for (let i = 0; i < inputsToSum.length; i++) {
    var s = (parseInt(s) || 0) + (parseInt(inputsToSum[i].value) || 0);
  }
  inputs.bounch.value = s;
  inputs.stems.value = inputs.bounch.value * inputs.txb.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="data-list">
  <table id="mytable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row" onkeyup="foo(this)">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="data-row" onkeyup="foo(this)">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="40cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="50cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="60cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="70cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="80cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="90cm" class="class"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: а если мы в 40см введем 5 и в поле 50см введем 5, а потом уберем число из поля 40cm то ошибка, а пото введем 1 то bounch будет 1, а по сут должен быть 6

Comment: @Aslero заранее описывайте ожидаемое поведение в вопросе. Обновил ответ.

Comment: а как выполнять в текущей строке? если мы добавим 2 строку, то все будет заноситься в 1

Comment: не уловил мысль

Comment: сейчас у нас одна строка tr, если их будет 2 или больше как считать для каждой строки tr ?

Comment: Изучите подробно ответ. Все расчёты начинаются при событии на строке (tr) через onkeyup. От неё идёт погружение к потомкам.

Comment: а почему, если я добавляю 2 строку tr то результаты заносит в bounch первой строки tr

Comment: Сейчас проверьте. Я немного подправил

Comment: о, спасибо огромное,  был близок к такой правке сам)

Answer (score 0):

Решение задачи (Обработчик повесил на onchange, но как мне кажется стоит повесить на отдельную кнопку "расчет").
Как я понял автор хочет получить сумму пучков со всех СМ. (Поправил код для корректности ответа)

```js
    function calc() {
        var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('data-row');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = rows[i];
            var elements = currentRow.getElementsByTagName('input');

            //Получаем все элементы
            //var cm40Element = getChild(currentRow, 'cm40');
            var cm40Element = elements.cm40;
            var cm50Element = elements.cm50;
            var cm60Element = elements.cm60;
            var cm70Element = elements.cm70;
            var cm80Element = elements.cm80;
            var cm90Element = elements.cm90;
            var bounchElement = elements.bounch;
            var stemsElement = elements.stems;
            var txbElement = elements.txb;

            //Получаем значения элементов
            var bounchValue = parseInt(bounchElement.value);
            var txbValue = parseInt(txbElement.value);
            var cm40Value = parseInt(cm40Element.value);
            var cm50Value = parseInt(cm50Element.value);
            var cm60Value = parseInt(cm60Element.value);
            var cm70Value = parseInt(cm70Element.value);
            var cm80Value = parseInt(cm80Element.value);
            var cm90Value = parseInt(cm90Element.value);

            //Проверяем что у нас что то введено
            if (isNaN(cm40Value)) {
                cm40Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(cm50Value)) {
                cm50Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(cm60Value)) {
                cm60Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(cm70Value)) {
                cm70Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(cm80Value)) {
                cm80Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(cm90Value)) {
                cm90Value = 0;
            }
            if (isNaN(txbValue)) {
                txbValue = 0;
            }

            //bounch равно сумам всех см
            bounchValue = cm40Value + cm50Value + cm60Value + cm70Value + cm80Value + cm90Value;
            bounchElement.value = bounchValue;

            //Умножаем bounchValue на txb
            stemsElement.value = bounchValue * txbValue

        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="data-list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Разновидность</th>
        <th>TXB</th>
        <th>40СМ</th>
        <th>50СМ</th>
        <th>60СМ</th>
        <th>70СМ</th>
        <th>80СМ</th>
        <th>90СМ</th>
        <th>ПУЧОК</th>
        <th>СТЕБЕЛЬ</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm40" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm50" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm60" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm70" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm80" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm90" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
   <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm40" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm50" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm60" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm70" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm80" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm90" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
   <tr class="data-row">
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="razn"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="txb" value="25"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm40" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm50" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm60" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm70" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm80" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="cm90" onchange="calc()"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="bounch"></td>
        <td><span></span> <input type="text" name="stems"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```